# Can a smart switch work as a conventional switch?

Tags: switch

Sorry for a silly question but I am very limited in my electrical knowledge. We have recently moved into a new house in Australia equipped with a control system for the lighting and heating. All the light switches are of the smart type of course but I doubt long term I will want to persist with the smart system.

So my question comes in two parts:

1) If the control box is eventually removed would the smart switches continue to operate OK if used as normal manual switches? I realise things like timing and programming would not work -- but I just want to be able to turn the lights on and off!

2) If the answer to 1 is 'no' could I then replace the smart switches by standard conventional switches thereby making my house "non smart"?

Any help gratefully received

Thank you
Andrew

Comment: The terms *"smart switch"* and *"control system for the lighting and heating"* are too vague to give a concrete answer here. Can you post pictures and/or model numbers of the devices in question?

Comment: Sorry. The system is an iCONTROL system and the switches are known as a Glass Euro Switch -- picture in on     http://paelex.com.au/icontrol/

Comment: can I ask why you don't like it? (just curios)

Comment: I am uneasy feeling that the electrics in the house are almost holding us hostage. Have been told that the system will be soon obsolete and not supported -- what happens then?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the answers to both of your questions are almost certainly "No".

As far as I can see, that system (like many other similar ones) does not run the power wiring for your lights to the switches.
The power for the lights runs to the control box(es) and from there runs to the lights themselves.

The switches are wired to the control box(es) using much smaller signalling/communication wiring - so the switches themselves do not see or handle the 'real' switching of the power to your lights.

Removing the control boxes leaves you with no power to your lights, and the only option you'd have is to simply bridge across where the control boxes were - resulting in your lights being always on.

You can't replace the smart switches with dumb switches because the switches and control boxes have a communication protocol which they use to talk to each other. The control box wouldn't know what the dumb switch is trying to tell it with a simple on/off signal when it's expecting to see a complex 'language' over the wire.

Unless you want to go through with the exercise of completely re-wiring the switches (replacing the small-gauge signal cables with larger power wires) you're stuck with this (or another similar) 'smart' system.

FWIW I design & program [commercial smart lighting systems](https://www.acuitybrands.com/products/controls/nlight) like this for my day-job...